# pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near 'INSERT INTO

Tags: python, pyodbc

I am using the pypyodbc library to establish a connection to a SQL Server  database and every time I try to execute a .sql file I encounter the following error at the Insert. But when I run this directly in cursor.execute it runs fine.

"pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near 'INSERT INTO"

```
                for script in os.listdir(inputdir):
                        if script.endswith('.sql'):
                            script_path = inputdir + '\\' + script
                            file = open(script_path, 'r')
                            sql = s = " ".join(file.readlines())
                            val = now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
                            sql_nw = sql + ',' + '(a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k)' 
                        cursor.execute(sql_nw)
```

In the .sql file I have added the query as :
'INSERT INTO dbo(a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)'

I Have searched a lot but have not been able to reach a solution. What is the error in the sql here as it works perfectly fine when executed in the script but when I try to read the .sql script I am facing this error. Also if possible please let me know how can I execute the scripts faster.

Comment: Are you trying to add the arguments meant to be given to `execute()` to the SQL string?

Comment: Yes. When I try to do cursor.execute('INSERT INTO dbo(a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)', '(a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k)'). But when I try to do the same with the query inside a .sql file and reading and executing it, I get an error.

Comment: You can't add the arguments to the string. Give them to `execute()`.

Comment: Yes when I add them to execute() directly, I am able to get the results. But since I want it the sql to be read from a file is where I get an error in the syntax. Can you please give a sample solution for this.